# Limit user on file downloads and file redistribution (discussion)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, download

I would like to implement a file download control for my asp.net c# MVC 4 web application. The requirements are as such 
1) Only Logged in user can download the file (pdf etc.)
2) Each User can only download the file once 
3) downloaded file should not be able to redistribute to others (this is what puzzled me the most)

For 1) and 2), I think these can be achieved by having records storing access information in database table.

However, I can't think of ways to achieve part 3) unless there is a way to limit the file content to query from server whenever it is opened.

Please share your idea and learn together. Cheers and thanks ~~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you said 1 and 2 is trivial since you can track it on the server.

Number 3 will be for you probably impossible to solve. Amazon, Apple and other big companies which need to protect copy rights of eBooks or MP3, they offer to download, handle this with [Digital Right Management](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_rights_management) Systems (DRM). However setting up such a system yourself, while possible, will be for sure not worth the effort.